# How to use $watch to see changes when updating a database record

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, underscore.js

I'm having nightmares on how to display on the UI what I have changed in my database. I have this scenario that I need to select certain titles and then I will click a button that will change its status.

Problem is when I select titles and then I click the change status button it don't automatically reflect on the UI. Here is my update function.

```
$scope.updateTitleStatus = function(statusId, cp){
        ContentAssessmentService.updateSelectedTitles($scope.selectedTitles, statusId);
        $scope.selAll = !$scope.selAll;
        $scope.selectedTitles = [];
    };
```

Here is my service.

```
this.updateSelectedTitles = function(selectedTitle, statusId){
    var self = this;
    _.forEach(selectedTitle, function(selectedTitle){
        ContentAssessmentFactory.updateSelectedTitleStatus(selectedTitle.id, statusId);
    });
};
```

Here is my array which is the selected title stored.

```
$scope.selectedTitles = [];
```

Can you tell me how to use $watch function? I don't know how to do it. I've done this but it doesn't work.

```
$scope.$watch(function($scope){
        return $scope.selectedTitles;
    }, function(newValue) {
        $scope.selectedTitles = newValue;
        console.log(newValue);
    });
```

I just need to update the UI immediately without refreshing the page (that's my last option but trying not to) when I have click the change status button.

Comment: Why don't you just create a factory that makes a request to the database and returns your data after the user clicks on the button?  If you want, I can write a quick example factory for you.

Answer (score 3):

You are going to have to use polling or a websocket connection. $watch does not "watch" your database. It watches @scope variables that are usually bound to the view and reacts to changes there. It sounds like you are looking for something more like meteor.js that keeps an open websocket and  will dynamically update the view when the database is changed from another client, background process etc. These are completely different things. To achieve this sort of behavior with angular, the easiest approach would be to poll your api incrementally and update models in angular when the api gives you modified data.

Comment: Yes. I am having a scope that displays the data to the UI. Now when I click the change status it will then change the database record and also it changes what is inside the scope variable. Now what am I asking is how to watch the changes on that variable? Name of the variable is $scope.filteredTitles

Comment: Maybe I can say I have that. I can already display my data on a table manner. For example a certain title that is displayed has a status of available. When I select it and I click on the NOT AVAILABLE button, it should appear instantly on the page that it is NOT AVAILABLE without refreshing it.